# Vagrant SSH Tunnelling after using `vagrant ssh`

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant, sequelpro

My MySQL client (Sequel Pro) is set up to connect to Vagrant over SSH. I've setup the following in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host vagrant
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  CheckHostIP no
  Port 2222
  User vagrant
  IdentityFile ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Everything works fine if I haven't run `vagrant ssh`. But once I've logged into the Vagrant box with that command Sequel Pro can no longer connect via SSH - it just says "The SSH Tunnel has unexpectedly closed." So I have to run `vagrant reload` before I can connect to the MySQL server.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: Your questions worked wonders for me when forwarding port 9001 from inside vagrant back to my local machine at 127.0.0.1 and port 9002 like `ssh -L 9002:127.0.0.1:9001 vagrant`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got around this issue by using port forwarding instead of SSH tunnelling. I added the following to `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 8306
```

Then connected to MySQL via port `8306`.

Comment: This was the only solution which worked for me on a mac running el capitan. I had added the permissions to mysql; removed the `known_hosts` entry for `127.0.0.1` + re-added; edited `my.cnf` file to make various changes etc etc. Importantly though, this seems the correct solution.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be an old key in my `known_hosts` file.

So, I did:

```
$ vi ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

went to the line with `127.0.0.1:2200` on it, then did command `dd` to delete that line.
`:x` to save, and bam bob's yer uncle. Connection granted, long live Jambi.

I hope that saves someone some grief. Cheers.

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thanks! Also note that if your vagrantfile specifies a `:private_network` ip address, you will also have to delete that line from `known_hosts` as well.

"bam bob's yer uncle" -- love that. haha.

Comment: Up vote just for mentioning my uncle. He will be pleased. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue. I struggled for whole day. I even went through  [Vagrant and Sequel Pro](https://laracasts.com/lessons/vagrant-and-sequel-pro) by Jeffrey Way. Still had a problem. I even changed forwarding port number in Vagrant file and did everything possible. But, the following saved my life.

When I did vagrant reload than I saw

```
  default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
```

But, What I was doing was when setting up connection in sequel pro I had written `SSH PORT: 2222`
I did this based upon the video from the above link. 
But as soon as I changed to the number I saw with `vagrant reload` than it asked me for verification. I did select 'YES'. 
And, it did get connected. Happy ending after a day of struggle.
Its for future readers,hopefully someone somewhere won't have to spend a day like me for this reason. ;)

Comment: For some reason I had it set to port 2222, I noticed in the config.yaml file it was pointing to 22, I changed it to port 22 in my sequel pro settings, then set it to my private_key file within the .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/ folder

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the another key from folder with vagrant project 
E.g. {vagrant_project}/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, it could be one of the following problems:

- The "insecure_private_key" is only used when the box is first brought up. Unless you've disabled the feature (insert_key=false), vagrant will replace that key with a randomly generated one, stored in .vagrant/machines/{machinename}/{providername}/private_key

  You can use that key in your ssh_config
- Your MySQL settings are doing something different if the connection comes from localhost rather than from the "external" IP address.