# The SSH Tunnel has unexpectedly closed

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, sequelpro

This is beyond me and doesn't make sense. I have a newly created VM machine (vagrant) that I am trying to access via Sequel Pro I am able to vagrant ssh into the machine but when trying to connect with sequel pro i keep getting this message. `SSH connection failed!` `The SSH Tunnel has unexpectedly closed.`.

In building the VM I have the `bind-address` in the my.cnf file set to `127.0.0.1` and set all privileges for the root. I ran `netstat -lntu` and saw this

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I searched for a solution but my sequel pro is up-to-date, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352212/vagrant-ssh-tunnelling-after-using-vagrant-ssh).

If someone can explain what other issues would be causing this It would really help.

Comment: please check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/31640363 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/22352212 I know I have read a bit in the past about it

Comment: comment the bind-address line or set it to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri if you look at my question you would see that `bind-address` is already uncommented with 0.0.0.0

Comment: humm ok but I read _I have the `bind-address` in the my.cnf file set to `127.0.0.1`_ so not the same as `0.0.0.0` so my suggestions are : 1) either you comment the line or you set the value to 0.0.0.0 and see if it helps. I am making suggestions here. I read your question

Comment: @Drew if you look at the question where I said I tried 'this' where the hyperlink is. This doesn't work for me either. and my sequel pro version is 1.1.2

Comment: @FrédéricHenri my apologize, Have had `bind-address` set to `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` same result

Comment: I was flying thru questions not paying much attention to detail. My apologies